# How to send an array with a POST request, with a parameter name for the array that contains an empty set of square brackets []?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, http, parameters

So, Rails normally handles parsing of incoming Arrays sent via HTTP Post requests (forms), like this:

> "Normally Rails ignores duplicate parameter names. If the parameter
>   name contains an empty set of square brackets [] then they will be
>   accumulated in an array." - [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#basic-structures)

But when using Net::HTTP.Post to send a Post request to a third party service (API), then it seems this convention of handling arrays in HTTP Post requests is not followed.

This code:

```
data = {:categories => [one, two, three]}
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
request.set_form_data(data)
response = http.request(request)
```

Then [set_form_data](http://apidock.com/ruby/Net/HTTPHeader/set_form_data) will serialize the Array like this:

```
categories=one&categories=two&categories=three
```

And not like this (which I thought was the conventional Rails way):

```
categories[]=one&categories[]=two&categories[]=three
```

Why?

I can see that it has to do with the recent implementation of the [URI.encode_www_form](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/URI/encode_www_form/class) method that [set_form_data](http://apidock.com/ruby/Net/HTTPHeader/set_form_data) uses. But what is the purpose deviating from the conventional Rails way?

And, more importantly, how do I easily modify this to send it in the latter way (without overloading a bunch of inherent Ruby/Rails methods)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found out that the solution was as easy as changing the table name:

```
data = {'categories[]' => [one, two, three]}
```

It even works if other elements of the data hash are `:symbols`.

I'd still be curious to find out why Rails makes this "hack" necessary when using the `Net::HTTPHeader::set_form_data` method, to get Rails' otherwise conventional way of handling arrays in the url parameters.

Comment: `Net::HTTP`  is a standalone ruby library. It has nothing to do with Rails.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the information. I edited the question tag ror to ruby to accommodate this.

Comment: Rails uses Net:HTTP, right? So the question remains why Rails deviates from it's conventional way of handling url in parameters when dealing with that library. After all, Rails could have had some overloaded methods or some interface to it that preserved its own conventions.

Comment: I don't think so. Looks like the only place it's being used is to generate docs: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d74c89ac16aa87f3bc166450e8d4b87382da17a4/Rakefile#L62